# How to achieve Bottom Align floated div that sizes to it's container

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

How can I achieve the following layout?  Specifically the positioning of `Image` and `DIV`

I've found that unless I set a specific width for the Div, it will just go on to the next line and take up the full width of the container.  Additionally aligning it relative to the bottom of the image is giving me trouble.  Currently they're both `float:left`

[image]

Edit: The two solutions so far work if the image is a constant width which I guess I could work with, but it's going in a Wordpress theme for an author's profile page and it's possible that images would have slightly variable widths.  Is there a solution that would have the Div right next to the image (minus padding) regardless of how wide or narrow the image is?  Basically having the div adjust its width to accommodate the image width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested in IE7/8, Firefox, Chrome.

[***Live Demo #2***](http://jsfiddle.net/krSAk/6/)

**CSS:**

```
#container{width:80%; padding:12px; margin:0 auto}
#top{position:relative;overflow:auto}
#top img{float:left; background:red; width:100px; height:180px}
#header{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0}
#content{height:200px}
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
$('#header').css('margin-left', $('#top img').width() + 10);
```

(you might want to change the `+ 10` for `parseInt($('#top img').css('margin-right'), 10)`)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <img src="" />
        <div id="header">Some text here that should wrap to fit on row. Some text here that should wrap to fit on row. Some text here that should wrap to fit on row. Some text here that should wrap to fit on row. </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">dfgdfg</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without knowing the width of the image beforehand?

Comment: It might be possible, but it would be more complicated for sure. The fact that it's for a "Wordpress theme" means you should have jQuery/JS available. Therefore, I think the easiest solution would be to give `#header` a `margin-left` of however wide the image is using JS. How does that sound to you?

Comment: Ideally I'd prefer purely css, but I'm not opposed to a JS solution if a pure css solution doesn't exist.

Comment: [Here's a version](http://jsfiddle.net/krSAk/6/) using JS; you can change the `#top img` width and press Run to see it. Now that I know what you want, I will have a go at a pure CSS solution tomorrow if no-one else has solved it by then.

Comment: the JS solution looks great.  Might want to put it in your answer.  If no acceptable pure CSS solution comes up by some time tomorrow I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the header image and header div inside its own container and position the items within it using absolute positioning.

I've put together a quick sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/JjxYj/1/

Notice here that if you remove the width of the Div in the header, it will become the width of its content.

**Update**

To answer the updated part of the question, here's another solution that'll allow the image to be of any width whilst still positioning the header text at the bottom of its containing item: http://jsfiddle.net/JjxYj/5/

Comment: The updated solution only works if the text fits on one line it seems.  The header text actually has a `<h2>` and a `<p>`.  I'm using `<h1>Some text here that should wrap to fit on row.</h1> <p>Some text here that should wrap to fit on row. Some text here that should wrap to fit on row. Some text here that should wrap to fit on row.</p> ` to test with.

Comment: It's a good solution.  It works.  Using ``position: absolute; bottom: 0;``, where the neighbouring element has ``position: relative;`` will solve the issue.  Just remember to set position back to ``static`` and ``float`` to ``none`` on mobile.